# Ideal way to implement iOS drill down table on a website?

Tags: website-design, tables, data-tables

I have an iOS app that displays small bits of information in drill down tables. It's for a list of schools, and goes something like this:

**[press]** Countries > (list of countries) **[press]** Italy > (list of schools) **[press]** Central High > (details of school)

I now need to mimic this behaviour and representation of information on a responsive website, but I'm struggling to envision it.

Is there a classic way to do this? Are there any clear examples?

Answer (score 1):

**The classic approach would involve a nested menu, like a Flyout, or Accordion Menu**

The accordion option may be more appropriate for your responsive implementation.

Try googling around 'responsive accordion menu' for some inspiration.

[image]